# Why does pkill kill my SSH session?

Tags: shell, ssh, remotecommand, pkill

I want to do something like this:

```
program='java'
ssh bob@mycomputer "pkill -f $program; echo 'Done!'";
```

But, it seems like `pkill` is killing my ssh (I never see `Done!`). If I replace `pkill` with something else (say `pwd`), it works as expected.

Comment: "pkill returns a non-zero exit code which terminates the ssh..." That's not how it works. More likely, pkill is killing the shell instance started by ssh to run your remote command.

Comment: You can test the "returns non-zero terminates ssh" theory easily enough with `ssh bob@mycomputer "false; echo Done"` and seeing what happens.

Comment: ah ok i was wrong - but my problem still stands. How do I make pkill not drop the ssh ??

Comment: Even if `pkill` is wrong, your "Done" should get executed. The output will be Done! with error that pkill throws.

Comment: I updated the question now.

Comment: Try pgrep rather than pkill to hopefully see what is being selected.

Comment: @Gilbert: Nothing is being selected. Its empty

Comment: No help for it but to try a ps -ax type operation to look at the list. I do notice that you use -f, which forces the entire path to match. Kind of dubious about "java" alone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well seems really a good case here. The `-f` flag uses the full path of terminal and if its unable to get the process then it kills all the processes it could like `pkill -f /` which includes ssh. Refer [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/407139/why-does-pkill-kill-my-ssh-session).

If you try pkill without `-f` then it works.
You can also check ssh verbose (ssh -v) to see what is happening in the background.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 2):

The chosen answer is wrong, if `pkill -f` does not find a matching process, it does not kill anything.

The real issue is that when you chain 2+ commands (either with `;` or `&&`), the `pkill -f` matches with the chained command and kills it. You can verify this behaviour with `pgrep`:

```
> ssh bob@mycomputer 'pgrep -f <random_string>'
> ssh bob@mycomputer 'pgrep -f <random_string> ; echo foo'
<chained_command_pid>
foo
```

Chained command in this case would be `$SHELL -c pgrep -f <random_string> ; echo foo` (you can add a sleep to the chain and go see it on the remote machine).